# growl.success is not working in Angular

Tags: angularjs, growl

I am trying to show message using  `.growl.success()` in my Angular code , it is not getting successful.  I have other views and controllers in the same application where growl is working fine.
*Error:-* `TypeError: growl.success is not a function`

In my **view** I have added `<div growl=""></div>`

My **controller** is :-

```
    app.controller('defCtrl', ['$scope','$http','growl',function ($scope,$http,growl) {
        $scope.allData = {};

                $scope.Go = function() {

                $http({
                 method : 'POST',
                 url : 'url',
                 data : $scope.allData
                 }).then(function(data, status, headers, config) { 
                 console.log(data);
                 growl.success("successfull");
                    },function (data, status, headers, config) { 
                 growl.error("Something is wrong");

             });
         };
}]);
```

I have gone through other posts too , and I found I have all the necessary files already included. Reason my other views are showing growl message perfectly. I don't see any wrong over here. What am I missing?

Comment: cane you add `console.log(growl);` and see if you getting the service. I think you arent getting it. Check and confirm

Comment: @ShashankVivek Nope , nothing is displaying on `console.log(growl);`

Comment: That's it then :) . you are not injecting the proper instance and so you can't find `.success()`. Please check injection instance properly.

Comment: @ShashankVivek Working now thanks for the help

Comment: cheers mate ! :)